# Combine dynamic arrays with dynamic keys in to single arrays

Tags: php

I have this dynamic multiple arrays that I need to combine in one array and serialized them. The problem is I need to keep both key and value.

```
$arr = array($bet_option_id => $bet_option_name);
```

Here i need to keep both bet_option_id AND bet_option_name. Then this result output:

```
Array ( [997650802] => Over 2.5 ) 
Array ( [997650807] => Yes )
```

This need to be simply

```
Array
(
  [997650802] => Over 2.5
  [997650807] => Yes
)
```

As it's dynamic, sometimes not comes with just single array so apparently I couldn't get it working. I need to retrieve both bet_option_id & bet_option_name. Tried something like this:

```
 $arr = array($bet_option_id => $bet_option_name); //This is where all array keys, values are stores
 $result = array();
 foreach ($arr as $array) {
     $result = array_merge($result, $array);
  }
```

Any inputs will be nice.

Comment: `foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
     $result[$key] = $value;
  } ` something like that ?

Comment: What's wrong with `array_merge($arr1, $arr2, ... , $arrN);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than create individual arrays like...

```
$arr = array($bet_option_id => $bet_option_name);
```

If you first create an empty array ( like you do with `$result`)

```
$arr = array();
```

and then add each item in using

```
$arr[$bet_option_id] = $bet_option_name;
```

Then you don't need to manipulate the array after - just create it as you want it in the first place.

Comment: The problem is that I can't retrieve numeric keys i.e key = $bet_option_id is always a dynamic numeric value.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - all I'm suggesting is that instead of creating a new array each time with `$bet_option_id` - where you call this at the moment, change this to `$arr[$bet_option_id] = $bet_option_name;` which uses the same values but creates one array.

Answer (score 0):

You could either do like Nigel Ren suggested which is the most elegant solution

In case that you do not have arrays that their keys are entirely numeric you may use array_merge. The quote following is from [PHP array-merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

> Example #2 Simple array_merge() example
>
> $array1 = array();
>
> $array2 = array(1 => "data");
>
> $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
>
> Don't forget that numeric keys will be renumbered!
>
> Array
>   (
>      [0] => data
>   )

Alternatively you can always join arrays together like this

```
$a1 = [ 997650802 => 'Over 2.5' ];
$a2 = [ 997650807 => 'Yes' ];
var_dump( $a1 + $a2 ); // result is [997650802 => 'Over 2.5',997650807 => 'Yes']
```

You can check more about [Array Types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [Array Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)